# Inconsistent FloatingActionButton padding with useCompatPadding on API 21 or higher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I have two mini FABs next to each other as follows:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/zoom_in_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_zoom_in"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/zoom_out_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_zoom_out"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This looks fine in most cases, except if one of the buttons is disabled (using `fab.setEnabled(false)`) **before** the layout is drawn. [Then it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqCTb.png).

The zoom out FAB seems to have less padding on the left and while you can't see it in this particular image, it also has less padding at the top. This only occurs when I use `app:useCompatPadding="true"`, rather than doing something like `android:layout_margin="12dp"` (which looks inconsistent before and after API 21).

This only happens on API 21 or later. It looks perfect on API 17-19.

My assumption is that there is a bug in the support library (I'm using 25.3.1) where a FAB's elevation is used to set the margin before the layout is drawn, but it doesn't consider the case where a FAB doesn't have elevation if it is disabled.

Has anyone else encountered this or is there a workaround? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a complete custom fab buttons from below two websites or write complete custom view extending from the `ImageView`, `ImageButton` or `FloatingActionButton`.

Sometimes its hard to control and makes an app to crushes if all the attributes are not supported like `useCompatPadding`.

[Android Floating Action Buttons Libraries 1](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-floating-action-buttons-libraries.html)

[Android Floating Action Buttons Libraries 2](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/173?sort=created)